# libpng warning: Incorrect sBIT chunk length

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, png, libpng

The warning mentioned in the title keeps appearing while trying to display an image in OpenCV2 with python 2.7.

How to get rid of this kind of warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pngcrush to remove the sBIT chunk:

```
pngcrush -rem sbit source.png fixed.png
```

In fact you don't even need to say `-rem sbit` because pngcrush will detect the fact that the sBIT chunk is invalid and will silently remove it for you.

You could also try ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick

```
magick source.png fixed.png
gm convert source.png fixed.png
```

I believe that neither ImageMagick nor GraphicMagick supports writing the sBIT chunk, so it'll be removed whether or not it is valid.

Comment: What are valid lengths of PNG's sBIT chunk (length as in amount of bytes)? I think removing the chunk could be problematic. It could probably be repaired in a hex editor or something.

Answer (score 2):

**sBIT** refers to ***Significant bits***. A **chunk** is used to convey information related to a particular image.

In your case, there is mostly an issue with the depth of the image you are using. The **sBIT** changes for every type of image. By type of image I mean: grayscale, RGB, grayscale with alpha, etc..

Visit [THIS PAGE](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html)  and scroll down to  **sBIT Significant bits** section to learn more.

Comment: How can i overcome this warning?

Comment: does this warning appear when you run for a different image?

Comment: No. Only for png image

Answer (score 1):

Try running your image through `pngcheck` to see if it is corrupt, or what is wrong with it. Then fix the source wherever you got it from.